# Triple integration of a solid bounded by 2 curves $z=1-x^2-2y^2$ and $z=x^2$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> I need to find the Vol bounded by $z=1-x^2-2y^2$ and $z=x^2$.

I have gotten
$$V=∫∫∫rdrdθdz$$
where the limits are $0$ to $2\pi$, $0$ to $\sqrt{1/2}$, and $0$ to $1$.

The ans is $\pi$ but my ans is $\pi/2$. Can anyone tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: How did you decide on the limits? Can you cite the original question properly?

Comment: Let E be the solid bounded above by the paraboloid $z = 1 - x^2 - 2y^2$ and bounded below by the surface $z = x^2$.
Compute the volume of E.

Answer (score 1):

$ z = 1 - x^2 - 2y^2$ and $z = x^2 $ meet along the circle $x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{2} $

So, limits of $ x$ would be $ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}<x<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and

$y$ would be $ -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-x^2}<y<\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-x^2}$ and

$z$  would be $x^2<z<1-x^2-2y^2$

So,

$V=\int_{x^2}^{1-x^2-2y^2} \int_{-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-x^2}}^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-x^2}} \int_{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}dxdydz$

$ \implies V=\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-x^2}}^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-x^2}} \int_{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}(1-2x^2-2y^2)dxdy$

Now, convert to r-plane.

$A=\int \int rdrd{\theta }$

Put   $x=r \cos \theta , y=r \sin \theta $

$V=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}}} \int_{0}^{2\pi}(1-2r^2)rdrd{\theta}$

$ \implies V=4\int_{0}^{{\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}}}} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-2r^2)rdrd{\theta}$

Comment: why is d tether from 0 to pi? not 0 to 2pi?

Comment: @happywand Sorry..I had somehow messed up on the limits.

Comment: @MyGlasses You're integrating the wrong variable for the wrong limits buddy!!